# Debounce on only one validator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

I've just read the awesome [angular page on form validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and I've probably missed something but how can I apply `ng-model-options` `debounce` property on a specific validator.

Let me explain the problem. I have a form that validate a public key and for that I have a directive called key-check that contains multiple validator. Some of them are local and synchronous like the format of the key and there is another asynchronous that check if the key is available on the server (asynchronously).

I don't want my server to be flood nor the angular application to be slowed so I use that the cool kids call debouncing and my input seems something like :

```
<input type="text" ... ng-model="key" key-check ng-model-options="{ debounce: 700 }" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="50"/>
```

And the directive is like :

```
ctrl.$validators.keyFormatCheck = function(modelValue) {
   // return boolean
}

ctrl.$asyncValidators.KeyAvailabilityCheck = function(modelValue) {
   // return promise
}
```

It's work like a charm but all the check are done with 700ms latency and I wonder if it's possible to do the keyFormatCheck without debouncing and the KeyAvailabilityCheck with it. I can probably use the old good way with $timeout but I prefer to do it *the angular way*.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can always pass a parameter to your directive

Comment: The problem isn't that I can't add property to my directive. The problem is, inside the directive, how can I set a debounce on a validator ?

Comment: Then, you add a $timeout accordingly

Comment: Yeah, it's precisely what I'm asking, can I do it with angular validator and not with a $timeout.

Comment: The $timeout will be part of how you write your validator; it's not one or the other. How do you think debounce is [implemented in `ngModelController`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L799)?

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ngModelController`'s `debounce` applies to the entire pipeline of parsers, validators and view-change-listeners (e.g. `ng-change`).

There is no way today (Angular v1.4) with `ngModelOptions` to isolate the `debounce` delay to a specific validator.

But the functionality is easily achieved by passing a delay parameter to your own async validator directive:

```
<input ng-model="val" foo-validator="{delay: 500}">
```

You implement the actual delay with `$timeout`; no reason here to avoid using `$timeout` on the grounds that it is somehow less than "the Angular way"; it's not.

The only trick is to make sure that you cancel the previous pending validation request before executing a new one.

```
var pendingValidation;
ngModel.$asyncValidators.foo = function(modelValue, viewValue){

  if (pendingValidation) $timeout.cancel(pendingValidation);

  pendingValidation = $timeout(function(){
    pendingValidation = null;

    // returns promise or value
    return doAsyncValidation();
  }, delay);

  return pendingValidation;
};
```

`delay` can be obtained from a parameter via a `foo-validator` attribute, either with isolate scope binding (`scope: {config: "=fooValidator"}`), or by directly using `$eval`-ing the attribute expression against the right scope:

```
var config = $scope.$eval(attrs.fooValidator);
var delay = config.delay;
```

Comment: Ok so there is no way to apply directly the debounce property to validator and not all the pipeline.
I guess it's the good answer, even if It's not satisfying at all :'(
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ThomasLeduc, right - there is no way. Whether it's satisfying or not, you can take it up with the Angular team and suggest an improvement, but in my opinion this would be too narrow a use case to implement for a framework

Comment: You're probably right ... but it's not so narrow, it's a basic case. Thanks for the confirmation anyway.